# Activating find/replace for jface TextViewer eclipse worbench action

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have made an eclipse plugin with TextViewer interface for displaying a text document but the standard find/replace stay in gray mode.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the TextViewer in a view rather than an editor. In this case:

1. Your view in which the TextViewer is used must "adapt" to `org.eclipse.jface.text.IFindReplaceTarget` i.e. its `getAdapter()` must return the target from viewer.
2. You need to explicitly register a handler for "org.eclipse.ui.edit.findReplace" command (which can be `org.eclipse.ui.texteditorFindReplaceAction`). Check out [Platform Command Framework](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Handlers) to get started.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Martii Käärik's pointers for finding the answer to this question. I've got it working with the following code, which however uses an internal string identifier from TextEditor. Still, here it goes.

1. `getAdapter()` in the view must be implemented like this (`viewer` is an instance of `TextViewer`)

   ```
   public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
     if (IFindReplaceTarget.class.equals(adapter)) {
       if (viewer != null) {
         return viewer.getFindReplaceTarget();
       }
     }
     return super.getAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```
2. In `createPartControl()` of your view, add this code:

   ```
   FindReplaceAction findAction= new FindReplaceAction(ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ConstructedTextEditorMessages"), null, this);
   IHandlerService handlerService= (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
   IHandler handler= new AbstractHandler() {
     public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
       if (viewer != null && viewer.getDocument() != null)
         findAction.run();
       return null;
     }
   };
   handlerService.activateHandler("org.eclipse.ui.edit.findReplace", handler);
   ```
3. No XML required.